# Best practices to design a 404 error page

Tags: errors, 404

What are the best practices in designing a 404 error page?

I read so many blogs and articles regarding this. Some says about using fancy images , when some days about sticking to the basics.

Are there any guidelines regarding this? What are the best practices?
Which of the following details are wrong or to be followed?

**Redirection**

- To home page
- To search page
- To site map
- Automatic redirection??

**Error message**

- Should we explicitly state `404 Page not found`
- Some other fancy user friendly messages

**Images to be used**

- Image relevant to the error
- Image matching the type of website

**Other page elements**

- Should the common elements in websites like Navigation , footer etc be included?
- Contrasting colour theme or same theme as that of website?

Any useful guidance is appreciated

**Edit:**

**Whom to put the blame on?**

In the error message should we specify that `the page you typed not exist` (putting the blame on the user) or some other messages taking the blame on ourselves even if the reason might be a wrong url ?

Comment: `404 Error not found` would indicate the error itself isn't found. `404 Page not found` is more common.

Comment: always offer the user a link to the site home page. pretty good chance your user, especially a newcomer, will be looking for a quick bailout

Comment: Whatever you do, *never* redirect (of the kind that changes the address bar) to an error page. When one types or copies/pastes an address, few things are more infuriating than not being able to correct the address because it's gone. (Especially when the Error page says "please correct the address". I've seen this.)

Comment: I once saw in a pet's store webpage the `404` error page had the `404` on it along with some random messages like "Sorry, the page you were looking for was eaten by the dog" or "A hamster used this page as his bed". It adds a nice customization to your site depending on what is it about, but also has to be noted that it quite depends on the user knowning what the `404` actually means.

Comment: @joshpart this might just be me, but i find those kind of messages annoying because i think of the millions of people out there who don't understand what a "404 page" is and who might be thoroughly confused by the jokes. Saying "this page could not be found" or "does not exist" is a clear way to describe the error to *every* user.

Comment: The "best 404" is no 404 at all, but the content page the user has expected to see, so avoid breking inbound links.

Comment: Also ensure that HTTP response code is actually 404, not ["200 OK"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_404).

Comment: @sgroves that was my point. Such messages are a nice touch, but can be confusing and make the user be even more lost.

Comment: @Vi. from the article you linked, [here's an interesting link](http://alistapart.com/article/amoreuseful404) with some suggestions on what to do with a 404 page from both visitor and developer point of views.

Comment: @JoshPart you are quite right, haha. i think my brain shut down in the middle of reading that or something :)

Comment: @sgroves no problem, as long as you don't get a `404 brain not found` error; otherwise I would be worried if I were you

Comment: @Vi.: Not every page request comes from links, let alone links under your control. You _must_ have a decent 404 handler in place.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10205208945130924&set=a.1595896305034.2078829.1464772822&type=3&theater

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't put the 404 code in the content of the page—that's what response headers are for. Quirky|amusing bits like _maybe a hamster ate it_ are fine, but should maybe go underneath a more-emphasized, clear “page not found”.

Comment: I just felt the need to mention this here... http://thebest404pageever.com/swf/catcatcatcat.swf

Answer (score 90, accepted):

#### **Redirection: should I redirect, and if so, where?**

In general, no.

Not unless you're pretty confident that you know where the user actually wanted to go (and in most cases, you won’t). It’s better to give them the explicit error message, and let them decide where to go next.

If the user is trying to reach an old URL which has been moved, it's fine to redirect them to the old URL. But you should really be using a 3xx redirect instead of a 404.

#### **Should the page explicitly state *404: Page not found*?**

I like having the 404 on the page, because I think many people know what that number means, and it acts as a shorthand for the error. But that's just a preference – for example, [Apple](http://www.apple.com/404) and [Microsoft's](http://www.microsoft.com/404) 404 pages don't mention it.

There should definitely be phrasing to the effect “the page was not found”. That's a common and well-understood message.

#### **How should the page designed?**

It should fit in with the rest of your site. You don't want to confuse people into thinking they've accidentally gone to a different site, rather than finding a missing page on the site they were actually looking at.

#### **Who should be blamed?**

Nobody. The simple message “The page was not found” is neutral and accurate.

- Putting blame on the user will annoy them; putting blame on yourself is unnecessarily self-deprecating.
- You can't tell whose fault it is. Perhaps the user typed in a nonsense URL (their fault), or part of the site is broken (your fault).

It's not appropriate to point the finger of blame; it would be easy to get it wrong.

#### **Any other suggestions?**

The URL the user types in can give you information about where they wanted to go. If you're careful, you can use this to redirect or suggest an alternative. (This assumes you don't have lots of similar URLs, and that you have some sort of finite list to compare to; this won't work on all sites.)

- I like the Apache [mod_speling module](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_speling.html). If the page isn't found, it looks for pages that are very similar (a one or two character difference), and redirects appropriately. It's a good way to catch typos. But it's pretty conservative, because redirecting to the wrong page is probably worse than returning an error.
- When it's too far off a genuine URL, you can still suggest what the user might have typed. This is an idea [from Brett Terpstra](http://brettterpstra.com/2013/04/07/fun-with-intelligent-404-pages/): his 404 page suggests similar URLs to the current page. For example, this is the result for `http://brettterpstra.com/2013`:

  [image]

Those aren't appropriate for all sites, but I think they're interesting ideas, and potentially a bit more useful than a generic error page.

Comment: This is a very well written answer. Marking as answer to redirect traffic here.

Comment: From a UX perspective, throwing bunch of links like the brettersptra.com is not ideal for it will lead to further frustration with many options to choose from. Quick question: The bunch of links you are throwing to the user, is it relevant to the reason why they landed on that 404 page?, giving someone more hard maths questions after he failed one hard one will make the person to quit maths :)  I think a  link to the website's sitemap is enough . see this post from http://alistapart.com/article/perfect404

Comment: @Chimdi2000 Yeah, that screenshot was probably a poor choice of example. Usually it's more like one or two links which are very similar to the URL typed in, or nothing if it's a totally bizarre URL. I agree that it could be confusing if you throw out too many URLs, but if tuned correctly I think it works well.

Comment: Definitely include the 404 error code. When the user calls the help desk, that is a key piece of information to have, and it will almost certainly speed up resolution of the problem.

Comment: Your answer is pretty good, but you forgot to mention attribution to the early provider of that URL (http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/84856/best-practices-to-design-a-404-error-page#comment135337_84857)

Comment: Technically, you *can* sometimes tell that it's your fault, e.g. if the request contains a `Referer`(sic) header pointing back to your site. Whether it's worth altering the error message for this special case is questionable; however, it's definitely worth logging at least. (Fortunately, most webservers do log that information by default.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen You cannot really trust the `Referer` to be accurate as it is sent by the client (e.g., often bots fake a your-site referrer for whatever reason). Also I assume that you already routinely keep an eye on all internal links and their validity.

Comment: I personally found this funny: ["I'm not saying you don't know what you're talking about, but I don't know what you're talking about."](http://transitiontech.ca/abc)

Answer (score 23):

I'm not saying it's perfect, but we launched a new 404 page this year and we included options asking people to give us feedback when they find a broken link.

Consequently we get a few emails a week which are helping us tidy up our site and fix problems.

We also included an obvious search box to try and help people find what they were looking for. We're revamping our sitemap but once that's done we'll link to it again from here.

I do like the Brett Terpstra solution (suggesting what page you might have been after), but I think that would have been hard for us to code, based on our CMS...

http://lawsociety.org.uk/broken-link/

[image]

Comment: The part about emailing was useful and new information. Thanks

Comment: I always wonder why that's not automated on the server side, with appropriate rate limits.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman Depending on the technology stack, it can be automated. ASP.NET has the [ELMAH plugin](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/) that when added will (by default) log *all* errors, and has a few ways to configure what gets filtered and what generates a notification. I'd be surprised if other frameworks didn't have something similar.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you intended, but my eye was first drawn to the big green scale on the right-hand side.

Answer (score 8):

I always appreciate a witty 404 page since not only does it convey that the **Page Does Not Exist** but also contributes to an experience that relates to your brand.

For example, I am a Part Time employee at Haptik and they have the *No Calls, Only Text* approach to improve Customer Service.

Hence, here's what they have done to theme their 404 page:

[image]

Observe the number of options it gives you below.

The goal is to convey that the Page does not exist, and you can use various metaphors to say that, but it's at best interest to leave a hint of "Page not found"

As a good design pattern, **auto-redirection should be avoided.** 
If you can have the User navigate to a section he wants by providing options, why auto-navigate to anything?

A good sense of how users end up on your website and what they mostly look out for gives you the advantage on theming the 404 page that way by providing multiple options they would want to go to in chronological order of their page-hits.

Everyone does this differently, and creativity is what should be your aim when creating a strong brand recognition.

Comment: A good example is Apple's 404 page: http://www.apple.com/404 (it has a more useful navigation that the menu itself and you still have a search field!)

Comment: Yep, pretty minimal.

Comment: I strongly dislike "It seems like you might have dialed a wrong number". I did not dial anything, I entered a wrong URL or followed a wrong link.

Comment: That's the metaphor. It's how you brand your product. The description is provided below.

Comment: Please note that this user is affiliated with Haptik, which is probably why his post reads like an ad for Haptik, rather than an actual answer...

Comment: I am. But it's an example I'm giving. I had to give an idea of what Haptik is before giving out an example. I believe the pun in the 404 page gives away a strong sense of brand recognition.  If you have a better answer to this, you could definitely give yours. I'm affiliated with Haptik. But that's not the reason I chose to feature it in my answer. The 404 page is related to good brand recognition and makes perfect sense.

Comment: Your post has been temorarily deleted. As you are affiliated with this site you are **required** to declare your affiliation (as stated here: http://ux.stackexchange.com/help/promotion). Once you have done so we will be happy to reinstate your answer (but try to make it read less spam-y). It's a valid post, but doesn't declare your affiliation as is required.

Comment: If I saw the "wrong number" message, curiosity would get the better of me and I'd hit refresh to see if it produced a random message.

Comment: @SwapnilBorkar - That is a very misleading 404.

Comment: @Rybo111: It's a part of the branding. As far as the description goes, it clearly states you the page does not exist.

Comment: @SwapnilBorkar I'm afraid the statistics from the comments do not share your opinion of the clearness with which the page delivers it's message.

Comment: **Unnecessary quotes are a pet peeve of mine:** Who are you quoting? It only makes an odd message worse. Sorry, Haptik, I think your message has been lost in translation.

Answer (score 4):

I will answer this from a human perspective since empathy is something that we strive for when working on solutions for users.

Assumption:
Three of your friends came visiting after they heard that something bad happened to you.

Website  = YOU that is having a bad day or disappointed or lost
   something and needed encouragement.

Image 1 = your friend Bob, Image 2 = your friend Ryan and Image 3  = your friend Liza

*Image 1: Bob*
[image: Image 1 = Bob]

*Image 2: Ryan*
[image: Image 2 = Ryan]

*Image 3: Liza*
[image: Image 3 = Liza]

Which of your image friends will you give a hearty thank you or call later for helping you remain positive when all becomes well?

I will leave you to answer that question. :)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what point you're making. None of these look like good options to me: 1) is confusing, it doesn't make it clear what happened and looks a bit like an advert. 2) is sympathetic but also confusing and doesn't offer any next action to take. 3) is clear to technical audiences, but not clear to others, and is needlessly dramatic and also offers no next action. Visiting a website is **not** like visiting a friend - with few exceptions, I visit websites to complete specific tasks or find things out, I visit friends to hang out (no fixed goal).

Comment: I must agree with @user568458. Your context is split and this makes your answer and examples invalid. Based on your exact analogy of "I had a bad day" I would choose friendly image 1. But the question is about end user messages, and so your image 3 is better as while not as "friendly" as image 1, it's what an internet user requires - information. If I'm on a website and a page cannot be found, I don't want "cheering up" or "a friendly face" I want information, potential solutions, etc. I can see what you were trying to do, though :)

Comment: Very interesting way to look at the question, but being an answer I think it is still better to explicitly give an answer based on your own thoughts around the question.

Answer (score 4):

To paraphrase Steve Jobs, design is 'how it works'.

A 404 page is something you want to avoid, therefore the most important thing with a 404 page is to design it in such a way that you know it has been shown and can then do something to make sure it is not being shown in the future. By this I mean logging. Yes, this will be in the server logs already but fixing problems from the server logs might not be that easy. If you are generating the 404 from an index.php point of entry then you can do something to log the 404 page, so, when it is hit you have pertinent information in a place where you can review matters easily.

A well designed website really does not 404 that often, the design is 'prevention rather than cure' when it comes to 404. This being the case you can keep it simple and to the point, so, if it does get shown it is clear to the user and not wasting your bandwidth on bots or other sources of incorrect urls. That means not bothering with CMS blocks of helpfulness, search boxes and other trimmings, just the 'page not found' with a link to the homepage will suffice (The homepage being known to load and known to have site navigation).

It is that simple. Yes you can add a simple image or have your CSS style it up, but other than that, save the hard work for the content you do wish for your visitors to see and fix those broken links in your content or in some .htaccess style rewrites before Easter-egging the 404.

Comment: "A well designed website really does not 404 that often, the design is 'prevention rather than cure' when it comes to 404." - this is a false assumption - most of the answers don't consider that 404s can easily occur from another site linking to a non-existent page in your site, e.g. some developer makes a typo or copies your url wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I use 404 pages combined with humor to make a better connection with the user.
I like to provide some helpful links and guidance.

There are many good examples of eCommerce 404 pages full of personality that attempt to increase conversions - some even with product recommendations. Perhaps they consider that the same as walking down the wrong aisle in a store.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the title: 404 Not Found.

Unless you are able to take them to a new location that will display the content they were expecting to see, I think that you should simply display the standard 404 not found error, with possibly some instructions on how they may be able to find what they're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

I like the idea of combining humor with a 404 redirect. I am thinking of displaying our latest blogs below the message to make for engaging copy. Our current 404 page looks really bad and has a high bounce rate- http://www.sevenatoms.com/article_writing_services.shtml